# Plugins issue of salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

When am try to authenticate my salesforce advance code seacher extension in my sandbox it’s getting stuck on the page after I allow it and says object[object].

Does anyone have any idea?

have tried require httpOnly uncheck and caches clear things. But still the issue remains same.